# Error signer not found - txInfoSignatories

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I'm trying to implement lock and withdraw of an NFT, but when I tried to check the signer on-chain with the function:

```
signer :: PubKeyHash 
signer = case txInfoSignatories (scriptContextTxInfo ctx) of 
            [pkh] -> pkh 
            _ -> traceError "Signer could not be found."
```

It gets always signer could not be found. Why it is not found? It worked on playground until today, but I don't know if there were some updates on plutus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the transaction has the correct required witness.

> It worked on playground until today

It sounds like you had this working at some point but now you don't, what's changed? There have been no changes to that repo for a few days now. Try finding the exact commit that supposedly broke this.

> when I tried to check the signer on-chain
> Blockquote

If you're using a real blockchain network then perhaps you're using cardano-cli? You need to build a transaction with `required-signer` flag.

Comment: Maybe there was some change in some days ago, I have to check . because now in the playground, when the script has a validation with error, the transaction appears between the wallet in the same way, and in the other version the transaction does not happen because it is not validated. I don't understand... it does not make sense to change a lot of things.